# When Regenerate Session ID Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-6

I'm building an application with login and I have read about regenerating the Session ID, using `$request->session()->regenerate();` but I didn't understand where should I use this, can someone explain me when and where should I regenerate the Session ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you see Default authentication then you can see for every login authentication they are regenerating session.

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        if ($response = $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new JsonResponse([], 204)
                    : redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

The main aim is to regenerating the session ID is often done in order to prevent malicious users from exploiting a session **fixation attack** on your application.

What is Session fixation?

> Session Fixation is an attack that permits an attacker to hijack a
> valid user session. The attack explores a limitation in the way the
> web application manages the session ID, more specifically the
> vulnerable web application. When authenticating a user, it doesn’t
> assign a new session ID, making it possible to use an existent session
> ID. The attack consists of obtaining a valid session ID (e.g. by
> connecting to the application), inducing a user to authenticate
> himself with that session ID, and then hijacking the user-validated
> session by the knowledge of the used session ID. The attacker has to
> provide a legitimate Web application session ID and try to make the
> victim’s browser use it.

As per documentation

> Regenerating the session ID is often done in order to prevent
> malicious users from exploiting a session fixation attack on your
> application.
>
> Laravel automatically regenerates the session ID during authentication
> if you are using one of the Laravel application starter kits or
> Laravel Fortify; however, if you need to manually regenerate the
> session ID, you may use the regenerate method:
>
> $request->session()->regenerate(); If you need to regenerate the
> session ID and remove all data from the session in a single statement,
> you may use the invalidate method:
>
> $request->session()->invalidate();

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session

Ref:https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Session_fixation

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#regenerating-the-session-id

As said in documentation ,there is no need to regenerate session id if using built in `LoginController`  framework does that part.

If you are using custom code , when password/username are validated success then you can manually generate session id by calling `$request->session()->regenerate()`

Answer (score 1):

What is Session?
In Laravel, session is a parameter passing mechanism which enable us to store data across multiple requests. Session allows us to keep track of visitor across application. Laravel uses a driver based system for session management, each of the driver is used to define where the session data will be stored. Laravel framework have following in-built session drivers –

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#regenerating-the-session-id

Ref:https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Session_fixation

Ref:https://www.w3adda.com/laravel-tutorial/laravel-session